# Automatically start a script while booting on OpenSuse 11

Tags: opensuse, init.d

I need the following sample script to run when OpenSuSe 11 is booting:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0;
while true; do
    "SOME COMMAND FOR SAVING i TO ANOTHER PLACE" &> /dev/null
    i=$((i+1))
    sleep 1
done
```

So basically just add 1 every second on a variable and then send the variable to another system. I saved this script at /bin/user/script.sh

Starting the script from console works perfectly..

```
/bin/user/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

First I added this line to the existing /etc/init.d/boot.local that comes with OpenSuSe, however this was not working so stable. Sometimes it was started and sometimes not. I thought because of user rights, but even after

```
chmod 755 script.sh
```

The problem continues. So then I made my own /etc/init.d/myscript

Content of /etc/init.d/myscript:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/myscript
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myscript
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     3 5
# Default-Stop:      0
# Short-Description: Start myscript while booting
# Description:       ...
### END INIT INFO
#
#
#
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting myscript."
        /bin/user/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping myscript."
        killall -9 script.sh
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Then I did the insserv command for my script:

```
insserv myscript
```

Starting and stopping from console works..

```
/etc/init.d/myscript start
/etc/init.d/myscript stop
```

but again no sign of life for myscript after booting.

What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully run a script every time when the system starts?

**Update 2015.11.12: This script is working and starting correctly on boot on OpenSuSe 11.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that insserv worked?

If you run `chkconfig --list | grep myscript` do you get any output?

Comment: `chkconfig --list | grep myscript    
myscript                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off`    On Yast2 I can also see myscript.. and running it from there also works perfeclty

Comment: So that indicates that it _should_ start.

Does a testrun of `insserv -n` give any error output?

Comment: Another idea - I sometimes add debug points in my scripts. Try to get them to print a date/text to a log file somewhere in different parts of the script to see if it starts, where it blows up etc. 

Maybe that could help you see if it even launches?

Comment: Thanks for the tip,, well it is actually running. Now looks like the problem is  "SOME COMMAND FOR SAVING i TO ANOTHER PLACE",, can not start before other commands in the system. I will contact the distributor of this special command for more details.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries at all - hope you get to the bottom of it. Things like this can drive you mad. I've had everything to the wrong start order to 'must use absolute paths' in the past.

Good luck!